# AtTiny45 read lag?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, communication, atmel

I have set up 2 AtTiny45 setup like this (The left one is also connected to power):
[image]
from which one (the left one) is generating a signal which is (when measured) looking like this:
[image]
The second one now runs this code to just pass the signal through from an input to an output:

```
int inPin = 3;
int outPin = 4;

void setup() {
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(inPin, HIGH);
  pinMode(outPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(outPin, digitalRead(inPin));
}
```

But instead of looking like the original it is looking like this:
[image]

The tinys are both running at 8Mhz speed.

Comment: The second one is also connected to the power line I just forgot it...

Comment: Have you tried accessing the registers directly?

Comment: No, I will have a look into it.

Comment: you could set up a pin-change interrupt on that pin (or a pin which supports it) and have it edge triggered, then just output the value of the input pin at that moment.

Comment: another thing is, why is the input pin set to HIGH, that enables the pull up resistors yes?

Comment: can you please update the question and tell us what the bit-rate/speed of the original signal is? And can you check that the second AT TINY is okay, by flashing it with the same program as the first one, and checking it's output is okay, and then flash it back to the receiver style program (with some changes perhaps)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams nope, check http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/DigitalWrite  it says: "If the pin is configured as an INPUT, digitalWrite() will enable (HIGH) or disable (LOW) the internal pullup on the input pin. " But it's recommend to just set the pinMode to INPUT_PULLUP

Comment: The Signal is basically the one the WS2811 uses. I basically want to decode it. http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf

Comment: I just checked the other chip is totally fine...

Comment: I dont get it, your left attiny isnt connected to power supply?

Comment: Read the first comment ;)

Comment: Its hard to tell without any indication which one is first/second/left/right/... Next time atleast put some markers on them. How do you have RESET pins connected?

Comment: They are not connected.

Comment: Are you using some arudino board or is the schematic as you posted (attinies on breadboard) ?

Comment: The AtTinys are on the breadboard as posted but I am using an Arduino as ISP to program the second one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23402/discussion-between-golaz-and-busti).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code, I am guessing you are using the Arduino libraries?

If so, then looking at your breadboard and your code, it looks like you might just have your pins reversed.

In Arduino-land on an ATTINY 45, the "pin" as used for for pinMode() and readDigital() does not correspond to the actual physical numbered pins on the device...

[image]

(from [this](https://engineerzero.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/attiny-4585-pin-conventions-for-arduino-ide-sketches/) helpful site)

Maybe try swapping the pin values in your code to this...

```
int inPin = 4;
int outPin = 3;

void setup() {
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(inPin, HIGH);
  pinMode(outPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(outPin, digitalRead(inPin));
}
```

...and attach your scope to physical pin #2 (Arduino pin #3) on the device and see what you get.

Also note that the digitalRead() and digitalWrite() functions in thew Arduino library are notoriously slow, so depending on how fast the signal that you are trying to duplicate changes, you might want to look into the [DigitalWriteFast library](https://code.google.com/p/digitalwritefast/) or direct port manipulation.

Comment: Yes I am using the Arduino IDE. Sadly it doesn't support the library so I can't test that. The Signal is about 600ns per send bit with a minimum of 200ns. Your code sadly does the exact same as the old one but the ports are swapped, so I will be having a look into port manipulation now.    Also does everyone seem to forget that the Tinys have a third PWM pin (Pin 4, Physical 3)

Comment: What would this code look like using port manipulation? I tried this: `void setup() {
  DDRB  = B00001000;
  PORTB = B00001000;
}

void loop() {
  bitWrite(PORTB, 4, bitRead(PINB, 3));
}` GIST: https://gist.github.com/Busti/82859493178cb16ab8fd

Comment: If you are running at the default clock of 8MHz, then a single instruction will take at least 125ns. Even in pure optimized assembly, for each bit you will need to (1) read the bit, (2) shift to new position, (3) write the bit, (4) jump to 1. There is no way to do all this in time to reliably repeat a 200ns (or even 600ns) window. Keep in mind that you need to sample the input at twice the maximum frequency (Nyquist).

Comment: I thought that when I generate it with an AtTiny I can also read it using one...

Comment: Could it work when I set the tiny to 16MHZ?

Comment: I think it would be possible to build a pass-though with the chip running at 16Mhz, especially if you were willing to use the USI peripheral. The USI on this chip has a quirk: it uses the same register for data input and output. If you set everything up right, whatever appeared on the input pin would show up on the output pin 8 clock ticks later. This would require physically changing the pins you use to (physical) #5 for input and #6 for output.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "proper reset circuitry":

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBGwCN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You dont mention from where you are powering your board, there may be to much noise and its reseting your MCU. By adding a stronger pull-up and a capacitor you're filtering out the noise that may appear on your power-supply or RESET line.

Comment: I added the circuitry but still no change.

Comment: I also added a large capacitor (330nF) between 5V and GND

Comment: I suggest you try to do as KyranF suggested, using a pin-change interrupt, and see if you get any output at all.

Comment: I am on it right now. I basically want to decode the WS2811 driver signal.

Comment: I am now done testing the Pin change Interrupt but still the same outcome.

Comment: I am using this code: https://gist.github.com/Busti/747ed0daa89d3de23ef7

Comment: The interrupt is also working when testing it with a button.

Comment: Decoding WS281x signals on at ATTINY25/45/85 would be difficult but not impossible depending on what you are trying to accomplish. Even at 16mhz, you only have a handful of instructions per bit. One strategy might be to use the Timer/Counter to measure the width of one bit while processing the previous one. What is the application?